# RubyMine suppression comments ignored by YARD?

Tags: ruby, documentation, rubymine, yard

I have been writing some Ruby code using RubyMine, which I have really learned to like, and have been using YARD for documentation.

I have come across a minor bothersome issue, that I have been unable to find an elegant solution for. RubyMine supports suppression of specific inspections on a "per expression", "per method", etc. basis, which comes in very handy for certain circumstances, especially for how dynamic Ruby can be.

My problem is when I want to suppress certain inspections on the method level, but these comments show up in my documentation with YARD, as it to reads comments to parse its documentation. Usually I can find a solution by suppressing the inspection within the method on the expression, but I am working on a wrapper that implements callbacks, and uses method stubs with arguments that "appear" to be unused, but are meant to be aliased by the end user.

I really don't want to turn off inspection on the project, or even the class level, and I strongly dislike the warnings being there. Just wondering if anyone else has come up with a solution to this little irritation.

Comment: Actually these kind problem you can report to JetBrain.

Comment: Always been to lazy to do this, but actually just did :)  JetBrains actually is pretty good on accepting and implementing feedback and suggestions, so I'll keep my fingers crossed for future releases.

Comment: thanks. I am using RubyMine as well, Love it!